# When I make a request to a server can I see all the requests made by that server to another server?

Tags: http, httprequest, google-chrome-devtools

I need to know which requests a webpage sends. Basically the site i call, calls another service/api/url whatever and receives the data (probably within javascript) and show me this. Can i see all the calls it make?

Edit: **concrete example:**

From this site (http://www.flickriver.com/lenses/nikon/) you can choose a lens, at that moment, the page sends a request to flickr, and get all the data. But in chrome developer tools i could not see this request.

Here is a screenshot of get requests. I have looked through them but could not see any request to flickr.

The first is request to the page. And the sixth one is the picture request already, where it requests the picture by its id. So in between other 4 requests should contain a request to the external source which gives the picture id in return or do i miss sth? 
And what if the backend makes this request? Do i still need to see this request in developer tools?

[image]

Comment: I suggest scanning over the devtools docs. They're quite comprehensive. Visit https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/. Right away you'll see a link for the "Network" panel.. If you take the time to go over these docs, you'll learn many over things you might not have known, and save yourself some future SO questions.

Comment: Your title is incorrect. You do not mean "Can i see all the requests of a webpage in my browser's developer tools?", but rather (apparently) "When I make a request to a server can I see all the requests made by that server to another server?".

Answer (score 0):

No, of course you cannot see the calls made by some server to another server. Why would you expect to be able to do that? Those calls have nothing to do with the browser. The browser knows nothing about those requests. The browser knows only about requests that it itself initiated. Devtools can only report on requests made by the browser. If in fact there were some way to spy on the requests made by a server to another server, it would be gaping security hole.